Active directory domain controllers and self-signed certificate
To enable LDAPS I need certificates on both domain controllers. I can't use Certificate Services as I don't have a spare Windows machine and installing that role on a DC is a big no-no, so I would rather use a self-signed certificate with SANs covering both DCs (FQDN and short machine names).
Anything should I pay attention? For example:

should the certificate have a maximum duration (ie: 1, 5, 10, 100 years)?
can this disrupt/affect connection with client machine (unlikely as the DC have no certificate at the moment);
EFS - not having a CA means that clients themselves are responsible for their keys. What will happen with the self-signed certificate?


It isn't required to host your own PKI infrastructure. You can issue domain controller certificates from a third-party CA. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/active-directory/requirements-domain-controller

LDAP only is fairly straightforward. If used for smart card auth additional usages are required. Usually if a DC finds a certificate in the correct store that is usable it will select it at startup. Clients aren't affected.

To enable LDAPS there is nothing special to pay attention to apart from the usual things when using SSL certificates. More details here:
Enable LDAP over SSL with a third-party certification authority
To answer your examples:

duration is totally up to you and your own preferences.
there is no downtime when enabling LDAPS first by installing a proper certificate, neither when renewing it.
the clients just need to trust the certificate, best through a root certificate, which appears in the chain of the server certificate

To test if your LDAPS is working properly you could use ldp.exe from the RSAT collection. Just change the the port to 636 and check the box at "SSL" when connecting.

the clients just need to trust the certificate - is this necessary only for clients needing LDAPS (in this case, a single one) or any windows domain clients will automatically start using LDAPS, requiring trusting the self-signed (or root) certificate on each client?

afaik the use of LDAPS instead of LDAP has to be specified explicitly on a client for it to make use of it.
If you don't want to take the risk (which there is none if you ask me), just distribute the root certificate via GPO.
